# Why the meaning of word "macht" changes?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

The literal meaning of *"macht"* is *"power".* But in the sentence

> Man macht das jeden Tag acht Stunden, dann kotzt man irgendwann.

means, according to google translate,

> You do it every day for eight hours, then at some point you throw up.

Also when I type *"man macht das"* it says *"you do that",* when I type *"man macht",* it says *"one does".* When I type *"does"* and translate it to English it translates it to a total different word *"tut". "Tut mir leid"* is *"I am sorry".*

Now I simply ask, where does *"does"* went from *"Tut mir leid"?*

Also, I need your opinion about the right way of learning this language. I've started learning it though TV shows as I successfully taught English myself (to a useable level) this way, but now that I've observed how word meaning changes depending upon the context in which they're used. I'm not sure anymore if I should continue learning this way.

Comment: Look up "machen" and "Macht" in a dictionary. They are different words.

Comment: Your first sentence contains a redundant "macht" instead of "mich". Also, words do not just have exactly the same uses cases between languages, especially not with fixed (idiomatic) expressions such as "I'm sorry."

Comment: @idmean: If you find typos like that in a question, and if such an error is not the topic of the question, you should not post a comment but edit the question and correct that error.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast There’s no value in editing a poor question like this one.

Comment: @idmean: There's no value in editing an excellent question. All questions that need to be edited are poor. Being poor the reason why you should edit it!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast and Idmean, You guys are really good at building confidence of someone who just started learning another language and had no idea where to start. Bravo!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Asking for opinions is not allowed on stackexchange. This is a reason to close a question. But questions about how to learn German have been asked many times here in German.stackexchange. Please use the [search function](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=learn%20German) to find some of them.

---

Now for the question about *"macht".*

One of the very first things you will learn about German language, is that **all** noun are **always** written with an uppercase first letter. **Always!** There are no exceptions. Other words are capitalized only if they are the first word of a sentence (like in English.) So, *"Macht"* and *"macht"* are two very different words. Both of them exist:

- **Macht**
  The first letter of this word is an uppercase letter, so it's a noun. Like almost all words in almost all languages is has more than just one meaning. Here are some meanings:

  - **power, authority, strength, influence**

    > Mein Chef hat die **Macht,** mir mein Gehalt zu kürzen.
    > My boss has the **power** to cut my salary.
  - **state, regency, leadership**

    > Deutschland ist eine wichtige **Macht** in Europa.
    > Germany is an important **power** in Europe.

  Note, that the English word *"power"* has even more meanings. But they do not translate to German *"Macht",* like in physics (electrical power = German *"**Strom**"*) or mathematics (the third power of x = *"die dritte **Potenz** von x"*)
- **macht**
  The first letter of this word is a lowercase letter, so it's not a noun. It is something else. The word *"macht"* is a grammatical form of the verb *"machen",* which can be translated into English as *"to do"* or *"to make"* (plus more than 10 other possibilities, depending on the meaning).

  The word *"macht"* is:

  - Third person singular indicative present active of *"machen"*

    > Georg **macht** Hüte. Jürgen **macht** immer solche Sachen.
    > George **makes** hats. Jürgen always **does** things like this.
  - Second person singular indicative present active of *"machen"*

    > Ihr beide **macht** Hüte. Ihr beide **macht** immer solche Sachen.
    > You both **make** hats. You both always **do** things like this.
  - Second person singular indicative imperative present active of *"machen"*

    > **Macht** jetzt endlich Hüte! **Macht** jetzt mal solche Sachen!
    > Now finally **make** hats! **Do** things like this now!

---

The verb *machen* has many different meanings. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/machen) lists 21 different meanings. I'm not going to explain all of them here. And the verb [tun](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tun) also has a lot different meanings. And also the englisch verbs *make* and *do* have lots of different meanings. And sometimes it is better to translate *machen* as *make,* but sometimes *do* fits better, and in other situation even other verbs might fit better. And this is true for *tun* too.

Generally spoken, if you want to express that something is created or built, then you have *machen = to make:*

> Georg **macht** Hüte. = Georg **makes** hats.

But if you want to express, that someone performs an action, you have  *machen = to do:*

> Kann bitte jemand die Tische abwischen? - Ja, klar, ich **mache** das gerne.
> Can someone wipe down the tables, please? - Yeah, sure, I'll be happy to **do** it.

---

The words *"tun"* and *"leid"* in the phrase *»das tut mir leid«* behave like one semantic unit. They strongly belong together. In English there is no similar grammatical construction, so you have to express the same meaning using another grammatical pattern, and the best English version is *"I'm sorry"* which again is a pattern that doesn't exist in German.

Note, that you **never** translate words! What you have to translate are **meanings!**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have a long way to go, in order to learn this language.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change. One is a verb the other is a noun.

Macht = Power
macht = (he/she/it) does (Third person singular for the verb "machen")

You should probably get a handbook from duden.de and look for a tutor. It's important that you don't learn a lot of mistakes in the beginning, because German is neither the most logical nor the easiest language.